# How do I check if a user submitted post, contains a word from a collection of banned words

Tags: php, laravel

I want to check if a post submitted by a user, contains any word from a collection of banned words.

```
$post = Post::create($request->validated());
$word = Word::select('word')->get();
```

I want to check if post contains any of the words from the $words collection.

Would the contains method work?
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-contains

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use already made library for this, for example [`Crudle\Profanity`](https://github.com/CrudleApps/profanity):

```
use Crudle\Profanity\Filter;
use Crudle\Profanity\Dictionary\GB;

$filter = new Filter(new GB);

// Clean a string
$filter->cleanse('Joe is a little bitch'); // Returns 'Joe is a little *****'

// Clean a string with a custom censor character
$filter->cleanse('Joe is a little bitch', 'x'); // Returns 'Joe is a little xxxxx'

// Check if a string is dirty
$filter->isDirty('Joe is a little bitch'); // Returns true
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure PHP,

```
   if(preg_match('/\b('.implode('|', $words).')\b/i', $input))
```

You may also want to do

```
 $words = array_map(function($word){ return preg_quote($word,'/'); }, $words);
```

Which will escape anything important to Regex in the word.

In Regex the `\b` is a word boundary the `|` is or so you get this for the pattern, the `i` flag is case insensitive.

```
 /\b(word1|word2)\b/i
```

Basically, capture word1 OR word2 (if match) with word boundaries.

[Test it](https://regex101.com/r/n5fW1M/1)

Comment: How to I use a collection of words though?